# How to know in which application keyboard is open?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a keyboard extension. This keyboard is available from all applications. Is it possible to somehow determine in which application the keyboard is open. For example, if the keyboard is opened in Safari, then output to the Safari console. Thanks.

Comment: Does your application is opening safari?

Comment: Hello. Yes app can open safari or twitter etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[KeyboardViewController.parentViewController valueForKey:@"_hostBundleID"]
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try, will write you back.